# Drawing polygon in image control

Tags: .net, wpf, vb.net, image, polygon

I'm making A program that do a star wipe transition between pictures slide show in image control in WPF by vb.net

and now i'm working on drawing the picture in a star shape in the image control

i done it in the form
This is the code to draw the polygon on the form

```
'here i draw the star points
  MyPolygon.Points = myPointCollection

'and here i draw the the star with the image from imagebrush
  MyPolygon.Fill = imagebrush
```

but I haven't any idea about how to draw this in the image control

I can put the whole picture in the image control by using the source property

but that is offcourse doesn't draw it as a star

is there is a way to draw the polygon in the image control ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't put a `Polygon` in an `Image` control. You have to add it to some layout container like `Grid` or `Canvas`:

```
canvas.Children.Add(MyPolygon);
```

Or in XAML:

```
<Canvas x:Name="canvas">
    <Polygon x:Name="MyPolygon"/>
</Canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this](http://writeablebitmapex.codeplex.com/) writable bitmap library to draw polygon on bitmap image at runtime and can set source of Image control to the Bitmap created.